# How to get image meta without downloading whole image in python

Tags: python, image, meta

How to fetch image properties height, width, size, mime in python by downloading only required bytes, so it doesn't take long to fetch a image.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you working with any kind of networking framework already?

Comment: @Blckknght No I'm not using any framework, but the python-requests library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating an imageinfo php library using threads. Here's the github link to that repository:

https://github.com/rohitkhatri/python-image